# Had to replace breaker box after power spike

Tags: electrical, grounding, neutral

Starting on 12/27/22 after a massive wind storm we lost power.  3 days later after using generator with no issues the main power came back on.  From that moment the power started to flicker, dim, destroy appliances, motors, fans and tvs.  It was intermittent and as sporadic as it could be.

Power company came by and said it was the main drop from the "weather head" ( I hope I got that word right).  They replaced the line from the transformer to the house.  I had good power for up to a few hours but then the problems started again and went on for days.

At day 5 they connected a recorder to the meter and I have that data finally it recorded about 10 days of data.  The data has some weird information.  Like when generator switch was turned on for generator ( total power company disconnect), the data says power was still drawing into the meter recorder.  Until I went a number of hrs without power company the numbers never reached zero amps in some cases not at all but still pulling 2-4amps.

I have 3-5 times when on one leg, high amps, 174amps  and the other reads 44.6 (voltage on that leg was 105v).  That is just one example the highest was 200+ with power being drawn on both legs to total more than that.  Nothing in my house draws that kind of power and I only have 100AMP service .  Their engineer says I have a hot tub and 240v 10HP motor ( no I do not) to cause that draw.  After the massive spike and fire in my breaker box I could not connect generator ( would trip breakers on unit)

Lastly they have replaced the transformer, I replaced my breaker box completely as it was dead from the spike.  Now nothing is going on at all beyond normal, still using same grounding wire same wires to various new breakers. Except to replace damaged, I did NOTHING to change anything.

Does this sound like my home or the power company?

Comment: With the amount of problems at the panel and outside, it is quite possible there is damaged circuits/devices inside the house also.  It is also possible someone made a mistake in replacing something.  Will need to have an electrician in to check.  It is not something to do next week but today.

Comment: I have already replaced all the dead/ malfunctioning stuff.  since transformer replacement and having to replace the main and only panel I have had no problems.  Remember I had NO issues pre storm only after power was restored.

Comment: Question is a bit hard to read.  Try to edit it with any problem you have now with the new panel and transformer.  Not sure if stuff is not working or you are getting amp readings with the main breaker off.  If stuff is not working, then the cables/receptacles/junction boxes might have a problem, loose/broken wires/connections or even some burnt wires.  With main breaker off there should be no power at all.

Comment: You mention "after the massive spike and fire" but you don't actually mention *having* a massive spike and fire, so **that's** a bit confusing. Was the monitor connected at the time? Also - Wall-of-text - bad. Paragraphs - good. [Edit] and put a blank line between paragraphs.

Comment: Is everything working properly NOW, but you want opinions on exactly what went wrong and when?

Comment: to all who comment.  Power spike was about a week after storm and power restored.  Massive chronic problems BEFORE spike.  No power problems before wind storm at all.  Now after they replaced the  all from pole they can including and lastly the transformer.  Then all has been great. Recorder  (Attached at the time) says amps all over the place both sides and 2-3 174-200+amp spikes on my 100 amp service. After it read steady in voltage and amps both sides.    Sorry for text issues only2nd time on site.

Comment: If you are getting the spikes after they replaced everything, get them back because someone goofed up.

Comment: _Now nothing is going on at all beyond normal_  So do you have any current problems? It's not clear whether or not you do, and what your question is?

Comment: Do not understand question? You need to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like something to call your homeowners insurance about.
You would be only responsible for the deductible. They would get to the bottom of the cause, because they will not want to be paying out.